# Multipart form-data POST using only default libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib

It would be great to get it done without any dependencies.
Here's how I'm currently doing it, but is not working:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            {
                'field':'value',
                'field':'value',
                'field':'value'
            }
        ).encode('utf-8')

req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com', data)

response = opener.open(req).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: why are you doing `.encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: I would use `requests` which though it's not in the standard library.

Comment: It says "POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str"

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, requests would really make it easier, but it would be great how to do it with urllib only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270518/python-standard-library-to-post-multipart-form-data-encoded-data

Answer (score -1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#data) and example in there, you do not need to `utf-8` encode the data before sending it to `Request` object.

So try this -

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(
            {
                'field':'value',
                'field':'value',
                'field':'value'
            }
        )

req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.example.com', data)

response = opener.open(req).read()
```