# Python 3.4 - Multipart Post Using Standard Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, urllib

Does anyone have an example on how to do a multipart post in Python 3.4 without using a 3rd party library like requests?

I am having issues porting my old Python 2 code to Python 3.4.

Here is the python 2 encoding code:

```
def _encode_multipart_formdata(self, fields, files):
    boundary = mimetools.choose_boundary()
    buf = StringIO()
    for (key, value) in fields.iteritems():
        buf.write('--%s\r\n' % boundary)
        buf.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        buf.write('\r\n\r\n' + self._tostr(value) + '\r\n')
    for (key, filepath, filename) in files:
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            buf.write('--%s\r\n' % boundary)
            buf.write('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"\r\n' % (key, filename))
            buf.write('Content-Type: %s\r\n' % (self._get_content_type3(filename)))
            file = open(filepath, "rb")
            try:
                buf.write('\r\n' + file.read() + '\r\n')
            finally:
                file.close()
    buf.write('--' + boundary + '--\r\n\r\n')
    buf = buf.getvalue()
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % boundary
    return content_type, buf
```

The I figured out I can replace the mimetools.choose_boundary() with the following:

```
import email.generator
print (email.generator._make_boundary())
```

For the _get_content_type3() method, I am doing the following:

```
def _get_content_type(self, filename):
        return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
```

When I change the StringIO to BytesIO in using Python3.4, the data never seems to be put into the POST method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: See how requests does it and then do that.

Comment: @IanAuld are you serious?  no help at all?

Comment: related: [Python standard library to POST multipart/form-data encoded data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1270518/4279). See also, [`urllib3.filepost`](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/21a288be4487040c6e21e27cec025b74d2a83152/urllib3/filepost.py#L58-L93). Both provide solutions that work on Python 2 and 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `email.generator._make_boundary()` would work:

```
import email.generator
import io
import shutil

def _encode_multipart_formdata(self, fields, files):
    boundary = email.generator._make_boundary()
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    textwriter = io.TextIOWrapper(
        buf, 'utf8', newline='', write_through=True)

    for (key, value) in fields.items():
        textwriter.write(
            '--{boundary}\r\n'
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{key}"\r\n\r\n'
            '{value}\r\n'.format(
                boundary=boundary, key=key, value=value))

    for (key, filepath, filename) in files:
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            textwriter.write(
                '--{boundary}\r\n'
                'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{key}"; '
                'filename="{filename}"\r\n'
                'Content-Type: {content_type}\r\n\r\n'.format(
                    boundary=boundary, key=key, filename=filename,
                    content_type=self._get_content_type3(filename)))
            with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(f, buf)
            textwriter.write('\r\n')

    textwriter.write('--{}--\r\n\r\n'.format(boundary))
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary)
    return content_type, buf.getvalue()
```

This uses a [`io.TextIOWrapper()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to make header formatting and encoding easier (`bytes` objects don't support formatting operations; you'll have to wait for Python 3.5 which adds `%` support).

If you insist on using the `email` package for the whole job, take into account that you'll need twice the memory; once to hold the `email.mime` objects, and again to hold the written result:

```
from email.mime import multipart, nonmultipart, text
from email.generator import BytesGenerator
from email import policy
from io import BytesIO

def _encode_multipart_formdata(self, fields, files):
    msg = multipart.MIMEMultipart('form-data')

    for (key, value) in fields.items():
        part = text.MIMEText(value)
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'form-data; name="{}"'.format(key)
        msg.attach(part)

    for (key, filepath, filename) in files:
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            ct = self._get_content_type3(filename)
            part = nonmultipart.MIMENonMultipart(*ct.split('/'))
            part['Content-Disposition'] = (
                'form-data; name="{}"; filename="{}"'.format(
                    key, filename))
            with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
                part.set_payload(f.read())
            msg.attach(part)

    body = BytesIO()
    generator = BytesGenerator(
        body, mangle_from_=False, policy=policy.HTTP)
    generator.flatten(msg)
    return msg['content-type'], body.getvalue().partition(b'\r\n\r\n')[-1]
```

The result is otherwise basically the same, with the addition of some `MIME-Version` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers.

Comment: There are `poster` (pure Python, standalone, no Python 3 support?), `urllib3.filepost` (may depend on other parts), distutils' upload_file` (specialized to upload files to pypi), `MultipartPostHandler` (Python 2), patches for ["multipart/form-data encoding" Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue3244).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: but the OP asked for a no-3rd-party library solution, so now we have another one.

Comment: I'm just surprised that there is no `multipart_encode()` equivalent somewhere in `email.mime` package in stdlib.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: there is, but it is [rather buried](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1cae77f873af/Lib/email/generator.py#l252); you need to build a tree of `Message` objects, and the resulting generated message contains a complete email structure, not just the encoded multipart body. You then have to remove the extra headers again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - thank you, I'm going to test this now!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Could you post a sample using the email library?  I'd like to see it done that way out of curiosity.

Comment: @josh1234: you might have meant to address it to Martijn Pieters♦

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you post a sample using the email modules to do the multipart post as well?  I'd be interested in seeing that if you have the time.  The other solution worked well too.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Thank you for all this information/help.  +50 rep for you!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - is there a way to make 2/3 encoder?  Thanks

Comment: @josh1234: I'm sure one could be written based on the code in this answer. I just don't have the time right now to do so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - no worries, I figured I would ask.  Thank you!